# Issue with <div> that has been assigned negative margin values in IE6/IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have nested `.disc_outer` inside a containing `<div>` element and assigned it some negative margin values so that it actually overlaps the containing `<div>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/fgpVP/7/

```
.disc_outer {
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;   
    margin: -120px -20px 0px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.30em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

I have an example of this in the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fgpVP/7/

However when I view this in IE6/IE7 it does not appear correctly, In IE6 any area of `.disc_outer` that overlaps container is not visible and in IE7 the text for £5000 has the bottom chopped is there a reason for this and are there any CSS properties I can apply in the to fix this?

**How it appears in IE6:**

[image]

**How it appears in IE7:**

[image]

Comment: IE6 does not support negative margin, if I have good memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to use `position:absolute;` instead of `float:right;`

Here is an update to your jsfiddle to show you what I mean: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgpVP/8/)